# Connecting a view with HTML

Tags: html, apache, cordova

I want to create a view for back button using HTML. Actually condition is that that view of backbutton should be connected to the another page when once if we operate the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you need to override the backbutton, then load your HTML page.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
  document.getElementById("target_div").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="target_page.html"></object>';
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me that what is the html code for the above java script to connect

Comment: I am not getting any thing by the above code if I run. COuld you please write the complete code